# How do I split a string by character position?

Tags: java, android, string, split, character

I want to split a two strings of numbers 12345678 and -12345678, so that i can insert a decimal point after the first two integers in each instance.  This is what i'm working with so far..

```
String googlelat = String.valueOf((int) (location.getLatitude()*1E6)); //<-- equals 12345678
        if (googlelat.length() <= 8  ){
                        //split after second integer
                        //insert decimal 
            //make string 12.345678
        }
        String googlelon = String.valueOf((int) (location.getLongitude()*1E6)); //<-- equals -12345678
                    if (googlelon.length() >  8  ){
                        //split after third character
                        //insert decimal 
            //make string -12.345678
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you're headed down the right track. If you want to change the decimal position keep your values in floating point form and use division/multiplication. If you want to format the number as a string there are better ways to do that.

Comment: Have you considered _not_ multiplying by `1E6` before calling `String.valueOf`?

Comment: @super_ not multiplying by *1E6 only leaves me with the first two integers 12 instead 123456678 and -12 instead of -123455678.  I need the entire number for futher use.

Comment: Stop casting to `int` then... there exists a [String.valueOf(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(double)) method. That is a side-effect of converting a floating-point number to an integer, namely _truncation_.

Comment: @super_ wow. that was simple enough.  thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it this way....

**1.** Take the String value into `StringBuilder`.

```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(googlelat);
```

**2.** Use `insert()` method of StringBuilder.

```
   sb.insert(2,".");
```

And its DONE !!!  Try the same way for Longitude.

Comment: See comments on original post for an easier method.

Comment: Easier or not depends on the implementer, its a way to solve the given problem, now its up to person to do it this way, or any other... thanks

Comment: Suit yourself. There's a logical way to solve the problem and an even more logical way to solve the problem.

Comment: There are N nos of way to solve a problem.... i could have shown all those here...but thats not what is needed by the questioner..... The point is to first solve the problem then go for an optimized Way..

Comment: Is the answer wrong !!! if not i dont think it deserves a negative point, else its a question mark on the knowledge of the person who negated it